# Can I make a Compiz animation rule for Wine menus?

Tags: compiz, wine

Wine menus appear and disappear with the *Glide 2* effect. This looks good for dialogs but not so good for menus. I would make a custom rule to apply fade in/fade out instead, but I don't know the window type for wine menus. I've tried using `xwininfo` but there is no way to select the wine menu with it.

Comment: It is possible, you just need to find the type of window that the wine window is and add a new animation that only matches these windows.

Comment: Sorry I didn't make my question clearer but my problem is exactly that I don't know the window type, and I can't even use xwininfo to get it. I've edited my question to make it clearer now.

Comment: Shouldn't this be a wine bug? If wine correctly identifies windows, then this wouldn't happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you don't get the normal menu effect is because there is no way to tell these are menu windows. There is no way I know of to identify them separately from any other WINE window or Ubuntu would already be doing so. :)